# Creating Launcher for Anaconda

Tags: 17.10, .desktop, anaconda

I've downloaded Anaconda on Ubuntu 17.10. I can launch it from the terminal using the command anaconda-navigator. It doesn't come launch icon though.

I've looked online, and have gotten to a Launcher Properties app (pictured below), but I must be entering incorrect values into the fields.

[image]

Does the terminal command not work as the command in the launcher app? And can the name and comments be anything I desire?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The anaconda3 folder is in my home directory. Once in the anaconda3 folder, I'm not sure what .exe file to even use, if that's what I need.

Comment: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator. I added this to the command, and I now have a desktop launcher symbol, but the program won't launch.

Comment: I've copied and pasted that, and the 'OK' button cannot be clicked on afterwards

Comment: Sorry, I meant add `bash -c 'export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" && /home/user/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator'` to command. `user` should be your username.

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.